# Can I remove the pump in my dishwasher to clean it?

Tags: dishwasher

My GE GDWF400VWW is making a noise  like something stuck in the pump. Can I remove the pump and clean it out? Do you have a video that would help me visualise?

Comment: Hi Louise.  Sorry but appliance repair is considered off-topic here.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Actually, my understanding is that large appliance *repair* is on-topic, but not usage or anything related to small appliances.

Comment: Louise, you probably don't need to remove the pump. I'd bet that you can pull a screen or cover from inside the unit and get there.